# Invoking AWS Lambda with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a postgresql db instance on AWS, I also have a lambda function.

I want to invoke this lambda function through a trigger function in my postgresql db.

I found this information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html#PostgreSQL-Lambda-errors

1. I have created a policy named "aws_lambda_rds_invoke_policy" with the permission `lambda:invokeFunction`. Resource is '*' because I want this policy to work with all (future) lambda functions.
2. I have created a role named "aws_lambda_rds_role" (Trusted entities: AWS Service: rds) with this policy attached.

I assume this role is automatically attached to my rds? (If not, how can I attach it?)

I have the following SQL-code:

```
SELECT * FROM aws_lambda.invoke(
aws_commons.create_lambda_function_arn('my-lambda-function-arn', 'eu-central-1'),
'{"hello":"world"}'::json
);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  unable to access credentials stored with the database instance
HINT:  Make sure that the desired Amazon Resource Name (ARN) is associated with the feature-name: "Lambda".
CONTEXT:  SQL function "invoke" statement 1. 0.000 seconds. (Line 1).
```

When I delete the role I just created and run the SQL code again, it works?!

Don't get me wrong, I'm happy it works, but I'm wondering why, because I didn't "authorize" my db instance to run lambda functions.

**Edit:**

A few moments later, it stopped working. Could it be I just have to wait a few minutes before all changes (like adding a new role) are finished?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, Even though i add a proper IAM role permission to the RDS it throws "unable to connect the endpoint issue". Did you find any solution @Sam

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the RDS role configuration was broken. The role association was tied to a role that no longer existed.

If anyone has this problem, try this:

On IAM,

1. Create an IAM policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Create a role for the database with an RDS trust policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Attach the IAM policy to the database role

On the RDS console

4. Open the database page
5. Find the "Manage IAM roles" box
6. Attach the role you've created to the database, using the feature "Lambda"

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same challenge. Below is all I did and works ticketty boo.

1. Create Aurora Serverless 2.0 - PostgreSQL 13.7 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit
2. Install aws_lambda extension

   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS aws_lambda CASCADE;
   NOTICE:  installing required extension "aws_commons"
   CREATE EXTENSION
3. Create Role With Invoke Lambda Policy to Specific Function and Attach Role to above RDS
   Example Policy
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
   "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region-name-here:rds-id-here:function:function-name-here"
   }
   ]
   }
4. Execute query
   SELECT * FROM aws_lambda.invoke('arn-of-lambda-function', '{"body":"foo"}'::json);

Works for me. Hope it helps!